# PHP array element as variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, element

I want to use array element as a variable in for loop where $arr1[$i] is written it is not working please help me ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php 
$shivam=12;
$raju=11;
$rakesh=10;
$arr1=array('shivam','raju','rakesh');
for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
  echo "The name is: $$arr1[$x] <br>";
}
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put it in braces: `${$arr1[$x]}`

Comment: `echo "The name is: {${$arr1[$x]}} <br>";`